# Create an Automation that exports Data Extension data only from the previous day

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio, data-export

I have an Automation containing a Data Extract and File Transfer that exports the contents of a Data Extension each day.

Is there a way to only export data from the previous day, rather than exporting all of the data in the Data Extension each day?

Comment: I believe you do have a field with a timestamp in that Data Extension?

Comment: Yes, it's writing as date/time though, which is causing its own problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a source DataExtension i assume (if not it seems weird).

Create a second DataExtension - "Daily Export of XXX".

Create an SQL that dynamically gets the data from the last day from the Source Dataextension and fill the data in the second DataExtension.
Will have a condition that looks like (assuming you have a eventDate field that contains the date):

```
WHERE EventDate >=DATEADD(MINUTE,0,DATEDIFF(D,0,GETDATE()-1))
AND EventDate < DATEADD(MINUTE,0,DATEDIFF(D,0,GETDATE()))
```

Do a DataExtract to the Safehouse.

Do a DataExtract to convert it to Utf8.

Create a file transfer to the sftp location.

Synchronize your sftp of salesforce or your internal one with salesforce.

Voilla.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't suppose there is a way of doing this without SQL is there?

Comment: Uhm, i am not sure. That would be the way that i would use because it is stable, flexible and i know sql to achieve it.

Comment: SQL is indeed needed, @ThomasHockey. This is the only way to isolate the records you want to extract